# How do I keep a selected value selected after form submit issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I am following this [article](https://www.integer-net.com/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/), where i have a dropdown. But after submit my dropdown has alwasy the first option value, not the selected one. In my case the dropdown contains all of the cms pages. This is my code:

```
 class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Cmspage extends Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $options = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->toOptionArray();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $this->addOption($option['value'], $option['label']);
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }
}
```

where my dropdown is genered. So any idea about that ? Thx in advance.
This is the content of system.xml:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <mynamespace_mymodule translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
            <label>CMS Success Page</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
                    <label>Cms Success Page Assignment</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <cmspages translate="label">
                            <label>CMS Success Pages</label>
                            <frontend_model>mynamespace_mymodule/config_cmspages</frontend_model>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </cmspages>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </mynamespace_mymodule>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you also post the contents of system.xml file of your extension? That might help people to give some advice.

Comment: I updated my post , can u check it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to choose some CMS pages and save their ID's in configuration for further use. In that case, you don't need a separate frontend model or backend model, only a source model. The config for your field should look like this one:

```
<cmspages translate="label">
    <label>CMS Success Pages</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type
    <source_model>mynamespace_mymodule/config_source_pages</source_model>
    <sort_order>11</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</cmspages>
```

And the source model itself should look like:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Config_Source_Pages
{
    protected $_options;

    public function toOptionArray($isMultiselect=false)
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->toOptionArray();
        }

        $options = $this->_options;
        if(!$isMultiselect){
            array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=> Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));
        }

        return $options;
    }

}
```